# using lag for creating an x+1 column

Tags: r, lag

I'm trying to implement a lag function but it seems i need an existing x column for it to work

lets say i have this data frames

```
df <- data.frame(AgeGroup=c("0-4", "5-39", "40-59","60-69","70+"),
                 px=c(.99, .97, .95, .96,.94))
```

i want a column Ix that is lag(Ix)*lag(px) starting from 1000.

The data i want is

```
df2 <- data.frame(AgeGroup=c("0-4", "5-39", "40-59","60-69","70+"),
                 px=c(.99, .97, .95, .96, .94),
                 Ix=c(1000, 990, 960.3, 912.285, 875.7936))
```

I've tried

```
library(dplyr)
   df2<-mutate(df,Ix = lag(Ix, default = 1000)*lag(px))
```

ifelse statements don't work after the creation of a reference

```
df$Ix2=NA 
df[1,3]=1000
df$Ix<-ifelse(df[,3]==1000,1000,
               lag(df$Ix, default = 1000)*lag(px,default =1))
```

and have been playing around with creating separate Ix column with Ix=1000 then run the above but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas how i can create the x+1 column?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cumprod()` combined with `dplyr::lag()` for this:

```
> df$Ix <- 1000*dplyr::lag(cumprod(df$px), default = 1)
> df
  AgeGroup   px        Ix
1      0-4 0.99 1000.0000
2     5-39 0.97  990.0000
3    40-59 0.95  960.3000
4    60-69 0.96  912.2850
5      70+ 0.94  875.7936
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `accumulate` from `purrr`. Using `head(px, -1)` includes all values in `px` except the last one, and the initial `Ix` is set to 1000.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Ix = accumulate(head(px, -1), prod, .init = 1000))
```

**Output**

```
  AgeGroup   px        Ix
1      0-4 0.99 1000.0000
2     5-39 0.97  990.0000
3    40-59 0.95  960.3000
4    60-69 0.96  912.2850
5      70+ 0.94  875.7936
```